# How renew ssl certificate on Tomcat?

Tags: security, tomcat, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

Following the go-daddy documentation :

https://www.godaddy.com/help/tomcat-4x5x6x-renew-a-certificate-5355

The flow:

I've create myDomain.csr and send it to GoDaddy , got reply from them with 3 files `( gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt , gdig2.crt.pem ,59a41eaec32d2046.crt)`

I mentioned that the old cert which was expired has a chain structure  , unfortunately Go-daddy give me  only "flat" certificates.

I tried to make a chain by myself :

```
cat 59a41eaec32d2046.crt gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt gdig2.crt.pem >> myDomain.crt
```

after that :

```
sudo keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file myDomain.crt  
sudo keytool -import -alias intermed -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file gdig2.crt
sudo keytool -import -alias root -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
```

and change the server.xml exactly as in the documentation

I Attach pictures of how in my opinion it should appear [image]

But Actually after my chain I had :
[image]

When I open the Browser GOT:

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to talenttribe.me. Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s). Error code: SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP

    The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
    Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

Learn more…

Report errors like this to help Mozilla identify and block malicious sites
```

Don't understand what I'm missing...is it Chain creation or tomcat issues ??

BR,

Comment: This error doesn't necessarily feel like a certificate chain issue. The message refers to being unable to find a compatible cypher suite. This would strike me as most likely to happen if you're using a newish Firefox and an oldish Tomcat, possibly with the cipher configuration having been adjusted.  Worth googling the error code (e.g. https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/2016/rc4-support-has-been-completely-removed/), and checking the appropriate SSL how-to for your version of tomcat http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

Comment: Which Java- and Tomcat-version are you using?

Comment: It works before the certificate expires , it is RENEW ssl....I'm using tomcat 7, java8 ,  did exactly what is this doc says ..... tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html  , I think the key-tool doesn't allow to create a chain , it is the reason i can't success to create nested certificate (chained) ... Saw some posts the only way is via open-ssl...am i wrong ?

Comment: Btw, changed the server.xml ------> <Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
              SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" executor="tomcatThreadPool"
              keystoreFile="conf/tomcat.keystore" keystorePass="!q@wDDfll"
              clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>

Comment: Help by voting and accepting answer if its works. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4):

You just need to replace tomcat certificate if your renew from existing vendor.
certificate name hexcode.crt Other no need to change. Its works for me.

`keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file filepath`

Comment: Thanks man it worked for me! I have tomcat9

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the tomcat.keystore is not being created with chaining intact.  To correct that, you will need to isolate the root and intermediate certificates in separate files, and then import them in a specific order.  To create a working example, here are some simplifying assumptions:

- The 59a41eaec32d2046.crt file contains only the SSL certificate issued by Go Daddy, presumably for an internet facing web server.
- The "gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt" file is a concatenation of the Go Daddy intermediate and root certificates.
- The "gdig2.crt.pem" file contains a redundant copy of the Go Daddy root certificate.
- There is only one intermediate certificate, and it is also the Issuer of your SSL certificate.
- The crt files are the base 64 encoded, or "pem", format.
- The tomcat.keystore file uses JKS format.

Here are the steps to create the tomcat.keystore, given the assumptions above:

1. List the contents of gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt:

   *sudo keytool -printcert -file gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt*

> The output will include delimiters for each certificate in the bundle.   The delimiter for the first certificate will be "Certificate[1]:", and the delimiter of the second certificate will be "Certificate[2]:".   Immediately following "Certificate[1]:", you will see the Owner and Issuer records for the first certificate.    Likewise, following "Certificate[2]:", you will see the Owner and Issuer records for the second certificate.   Also note:
>
> - The root certificate is unique in that the Owner is the same as the Issuer (in other words, it is self-signed).
> - The root certificate is also the Issuer of the intermediate certificate.

2. List the contents of gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt in "rfc" format:

   *sudo keytool -printcert -file gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt -rfc*

> Again, note the delimiters "Certificate[1]:" and "Certificate[2]:" are used with the same meaning as above.  But in rfc format, the certificates are listed using base 64 "pem" format starting  with "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and ending with "-----END CERTIFICATE-----".  That is format that will be needed in the separate root and intermediate certificate files.

3. Redirect the output of step 2 to a temporary file.   Then use a text editor to save the Go Daddy root certificate in a separate file named gd_root.crt.

> Be certain to include the entirety of the text beginning with "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and ending with "-----END CERTIFICATE-----".

4. Likewise, save the Go Daddy intermediate certificate in a separate file named gd_intermediate.crt.
5. Use the "keytool -importcert" command to create the keystore incrementally:

   *sudo keytool -importcert -noprompt -file gd_intermediate.crt  -alias intermed -keystore tomcat.keystore -storepass '!q@wDDfll'*

   *sudo keytool -importcert -noprompt -file gd_root.crt          -alias root     -keystore tomcat.keystore -storepass '!q@wDDfll'*

   *sudo keytool -importcert -noprompt -file 59a41eaec32d2046.crt -alias tomcat   -keystore tomcat.keystore -storepass '!q@wDDfll'*

> The order of the commands above is important.  You need to create the keystore first using the intermediate certificate used by the CA to issue (sign) your SSL certificate.   (*If there are additional intermediate certificates, those would be added next, until the final intermediate certificate, which is signed by the root certificate, is added.*)  Next, you add the root certificate.  And finally, you add the SSL certificate issued by the CA for your application.
>
> This will fix the issue with the tomcat.keystore file.   You might also consider building a custom trust store file, which requires the truststoreFile and truststorePass options within the connector element, as an alternative to relying on Java's cacerts trust store.  The commands to do that are similar to the fist 2 commands above, substituting the trust store file name along with the trust store password.