# How to install a SSL from godaddy on Tomcat server, which is hosted on Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, tomcat, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I am trying to install a jks certificate which I generated using following commands:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out my-cert.pfx -inkey www.mydomain.com.key -in www.mydomain.com.crt
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore my-cert.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore key-store-name.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

The server is Tomcat based and it is hosted on EC2 instance. The key and crt file I got from GoDaddy, which was made for a different domain (lets call it *mydomain.com*). Additionally, I also created subdomain on GoDaddy, which points to the ip address of the instance ec2. However, https://dashboard.mydomain.com:8080/ returns **error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG**. While it was supposed be an html page.

Could you please someone provide guideline how to do this properly? Neither AWS nor GoDaddy provides enough info about it.

(I have already tried multiple times with different ssls before and searched google thoroughly)

P.S. I also used Route 53 which redirects https://dashboard.mydomain.com/ to the ip address of the ec2 instance. I am not sure if I was supposed to do this, because I already did it on GoDaddy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is issue you are getting because if you follow godaddy guidelines it will help. https://in.godaddy.com/help/install-ssl-certificates-16623

Comment: No need to do with Route53. Only your 443 port has to enable under security group. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46149543/how-renew-ssl-certificate-on-tomcat/52252653#52252653 this can help you.

Comment: Thanks
I will check the links you shared shortly and update you

Comment: @aviboy2006 thanks for the link it helped me to setup the load balancer and install the certificate, but I am still trying to figure out how to access the instance by subdomain instead of public ip address

Comment: if you are using ELB then map that ELB to subdomain A record in Route53.

Comment: Okay, I am gonna try that and update you

Comment: but didn't you said that there is no need for Route53?

Comment: @aviboy2006 I managed to route traffic of subdomain to the instance from GoDaddy DNS panel, now it is just about SSL. Thanks for help

Comment: Great. Good to hear. Its help you.